# Поиск на PHP

Tags: поиск, html, php, mysql

Доброго времени суток! Возникла необходимость сделать поиск по сайту на PHP, но не знаю, как его реализовать. Напишите, пожалуйста, код скрипта поиска по сайту, использующий для вывода данные из MySQL.

У меня есть 3 столбца в таблице: id, name, icon. Нужно, чтобы в html форму (шаблон) выводились результаты поиска.

Вот html-форма.

```
<a href="news.php?id=91">
<img src="images/83756_38576.jpg" width="581" height="233">
</a><p>Сайт на реконструкции</p></li>
```

Помогите пожалуйста с кодом, а то когда искал способ реализации поиска, то ничего не понял...

Comment: Вы сами поняли что написали?

Comment: > ... Напишите, пожалуйста, код скрипта поиска по сайту ...

@Аноки, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к предложениям выполнить работу.

Comment: Да форма у вас конечно классная! А на ваш вопрос ответили выше!

Answer (score 3):

По тексту делаешь запрос к базе с помощью `LIKE %text%` и выводишь результат

Comment: Ну это примитив. Вообще лучше готовые заюзать: [Какой алгоритм лучше всего использовать для поиска в тексте?][1] 


  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/questions/159793/php-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC-%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=159800#159800

Comment: @lampa Использование [проекта][1] г-на Аксёнова бесспорно идеальное решение, если используется система отличная от виртуального хостинга, в противном же случае FULLTEXT-MATCH|LIKE наше всё.
В "эконом-проектах" успешно применяю связку MATCH с установкой веса по полям и phpmorphy. Для более высокой точности, можно пойти и на небольшое переполнение в БД - добавить пару полей со словоформами.
  [1]: http://sphinxsearch.com/

Answer (score 2):

Судя по всему вы делаете первые попытки в освоении web-ремесла, а потому, стоит начинать с LIKE, а лучше с FULLTEXT-MATCH.

Создаём таблицу:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
`name` text,
`icon` varchar(200),
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
FULLTEXT KEY (`name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Заполняем таблицу:

```
INSERT INTO tbl VALUES
 (NULL, 'rolf', '/img/1.png'),
 (NULL, 'mark', '/img/2.png'),
 (NULL, 'bob', '/img/3.png');
```

Собственно, бизнес-логика:

```
try {
    $DBH = new PDO(
        'mysql:
        host=localhost;
        dbname=test;
        charset=utf8;',
        'user',
        'pass'
    )
    $DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $query = 'SELECT name, icon FROM `tbl` WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST (:text_search)';
    $query_param = array(
        'text_search' => 'mark'
    );

    /**
     * Если с LIKE:
     *
     * $query = 'SELECT name, icon FROM `tbl` WHERE name LIKE :text_search';
     * $query_param = array(
        'text_search' => '%mark%'
       );
     */

    $STH = $DBH->prepare($query);
    $STH->execute($query_param);
    $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $arr_res = array();
    if ($STH->rowCount() > 0) {
        $arr_res = $STH->fetchAll();
    }

/* Если вызвано исключение (ошибка) */
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

/* Парсинг */
$str = '';
foreach ($arr_res as $value) {
    $str .= '<div><img src="' . $value['icon'] . '">' . $value['name'] . '</div>';
}
echo $str;
```

Статьи в помощь:

[Полнотекстовый поиск и его возможности](http://habrahabr.ru/post/40218/)

[Почему стоит пользоваться PDO для работы с базой данных](http://habrahabr.ru/post/137664/)

P.S. Могут быть проблемы, если задан поисковый запрос, состоящий меньше, чем из 4-х символов, т.к. параметр "ft_min_word_len" в настройках MySQL по-умолчанию установлен "4". Оператор "LIKE" не имеет никаких ограничений.